# Phonegap SQLite error processing 5: No. of '?' doesn't match

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, insert, phonegap-build

I am not getting what's happening with my codes. I don't know why I am getting No. of '?'s in statement string doesn't match arguement count while I am not using '?' to insert values. Here is my code:

```
    db = window.openDatabase("myDB", "1.0", "Test DB", 2000000);
        db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);

            $.ajax({

            type: 'POST',
            url: "MY_SERVER_URL",
            data: {"email": email, "password": password},
            success: function (response) {
                     db.transaction(function (tx) { saveDetailsInDB(tx, JSON.stringify(response)) } ,errorCB , successInsertion);

            },
            error: function (errorMessage) {
                window.alert("Something went wrong!");

            }

        });


        }   
    }

function populateDB(tx) {
            tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS UserDetailsInJSONform');
            tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS UserDetailsInJSONform (ID INTEGER, JSONdetails TEXT)');
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO UserDetailsInJSONform (ID,JSONdetails) VALUES (1,"asd")');
}


function saveDetailsInDB(tx, response){
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO UserDetailsInJSONform (ID,JSONdetails) VALUES (1,"asd")',done,errorCB);
}


function done(tx) {
    alert("success ");
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM UserDetailsInJSONform', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
}


// Transaction error callback
function errorCB(err) {
    alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code+" "+err.message);
}


// Transaction success callback
function successCB() {
     alert("Positive successCB");
}


function successInsertion() {
     alert("Positive successInsertion");
}


function querySuccess(tx,results){
        var len = results.rows.length;
        alert("Row no. "+len);

        for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
            alert(results.rows.item(i).ID);
            alert(results.rows.item(i).JSONdetails );
        }   

}
```

I am beginner in Phonegap. I tried to save my returned data from server in local SQLite DB. But I don't know why I am getting unknown errors. Please Help me !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2nd argument in tx.executeSql expects values between brackets.
            `tx.executeSql(sqlToExecuteForTx,bracketValuesForTx,success,error);`

In your code:
    `tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO UserDetailsInJSONform (ID,JSONdetails) VALUES (1,"asd")',done,errorCB);`

It has 'done' as second value which refers to a function in your code. I would recommand to use: 
    `tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO UserDetailsInJSONform (ID,JSONdetails) VALUES (?,?)',[1,"asd"],done,errorCB);`

Comment: Sorry for replying late but I tried codes and that worked, Thank you so much @nyluje . You saved my life!!! :)